# Awk can only print the whole line; cannot access the specific fields

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am currently working on my capstone project for Unix OS I.  I'm very close to finishing, but I'm stuck on this part: basically, my assignment is to create a menu-based application wherein a user can enter a first and last name, I take that data, use it create a user name, and then I translate it from lowercase to uppercase, and finally store the data as: **firstname:lastname:username**.

When asked to display the data I must display it based on the username instead of the first name, and formatted with spaces instead of tabs. For example, it should look like: **username firstname lastname**.  So, I've tried multiple commands, such as sort and awk, but I seem to be only able to access the fields in the file as one big field; e.g  when I do `awk '{print NF}' users.txt` to find the number of fields per row, it will return 1, clearly showing that my data is only being entered as one field, instead of the necessary 3 I need.  So my question is this: how do I go about changing the number of fields in the text file?  Here is my code to add the firstname:lastname:username to the file users.txt:

```
userInfo=~/capstoneProject/users.txt
#make sure strings is not empty before writing to disk
if [[ "$fname" != ""  &&  "$lname" != "" ]]
then    #write to userInfo (users.txt)
echo "$fname:$lname:$uname" | tr a-z A-Z >> $userInfo
#change to uppercase using |
fi
```

Is it because of the way I am entering the data into my file? Using `echo "$fname:$lname:$uname"` ?  Because this is the way my textbook showed me how to do it, and they had no trouble later on when using the sort function with specific fields, as I am trying to do now.  If more detail is necessary, please let me know; this is the last thing I need before I can submit my project, due tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file has `:`-separated fields so you need to tell awk that:

```
awk -F':' '{print NF}' users.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful as I was then able to use awk -F':' '{print $3, $1, $2}' users.txt to get the output necessary. Not sure why I didn't realize this at first; now, how can I use this command in my shell script menu? >> my menu uses a case statement with the format:                                                                     'case $choice in [Pp]) awk -F':' '{print $3, $1, $2}' users.txt;;`

Comment: You're welcome. Ask a new question. Chameleon questions are frowned up in this forum.

Comment: Got it, sorry, I am a noob to the forums and programming as you can tell, and I figured the other question out anyway.